# How to get table value?

Tags: lua

Im trying to get the value from this , but it's return as a table

```
for i=1, #xPlayer.inventory, 1 do
    if xPlayer.inventory[i].count > 0 then
        dd = table.unpack(xPlayer.inventory)
        print(dd)
    end
end
```

The result for 3 items :

```
table: 0x7f0900084620
table: 0x7f0900084620
table: 0x7f0900084620
```

How do i get each item value ?

Comment: The three items are the same table - Instead of only ```print(dd)``` use: ```for key,value in pairs(dd) do print(key,value) end```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed , for my issue it's already has a value on each list so i just need to do like

data.prop

or data["prop"]

for example

This result the item count on each list :

```
xPlayer.inventory[i].count
```

This result the item name on each list :

```
xPlayer.inventory[i].name
```

This result both of the list

```
a = xPlayer.inventory[i].name 
b = xPlayer.inventory[i].count 
print(a .." "..b)
```